# In which scenarios is the derivative of mass moment of inertia ignored and taken into consideration for rigid bodies?

Tags: angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

When taking the time derivative of Angular Momentum

[image]

The first two terms represent the relative rate of change with respect to the coordinate system used. Most sources I have been reading state that the 
derivative of mass moment of inertia (2nd term) is equal to zeros for rigid bodies. Can you please help me understand why can we make this assumption?

Also, does the same assumption hold for variable mass systems, like a plane (fuel consumption)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass moment of inertia is purely a function of the mass density distribution of the object. If the object is a rigid body, its mass density distribution is constant by definition (different mass elements don't move or change relative to each other), hence the derivative is zero.

For variable-mass systems, the mass density distribution is not constant. The escape of fuel from the system consititutes a deformation of the system (as the fuel is moving relative to the plane), which means it's not a rigid body.